# Purpose of THROW statement without parametes

Tags: sql-server, try-catch

What is the difference between "using a `THROW` statement without any parameters in `TRY..CATCH` block" & absence of `TRY..CATCH` block in any SQL Server stored procedure?

Scenario 1:

```
BEGIN TRY
  ....
  ....
  ....
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  THROW;
END CATCH
```

Scenario 2:

```
  ....
  ....
  Code with no TRY CATCH block.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ee677615.aspx):

> Raises an exception and transfers execution to a CATCH block of a
>   TRY…CATCH construct in SQL Server 2016.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The statement before the THROW statement must be followed by the
>   semicolon (;) statement terminator.
>
> If a TRY…CATCH construct is not available, the session is ended. The
>   line number and procedure where the exception is raised are set. The
>   severity is set to 16.
>
> If the THROW statement is specified without parameters, it must appear
>   inside a CATCH block. This causes the caught exception to be raised.
>   Any error that occurs in a THROW statement causes the statement batch
>   to be ended.

Comment: Thanks for this link. But I am trying to think of possible scenarios where these two approaches are suitable. If I am calling the Stored Procedure from .Net code, then will I get back different error? How it will make any difference to me?